# IE9 RC and jQuery drag and drop is not working

Tags: internet-explorer-9

IE9 RC and jQuery drag/drop is not working. Somebody has a solution?

Answer (score 3):

1. Upgrade to IE9 RTM.
2. Upgrade to the latest JQuery version.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/02/jquery-1-5-1-supports-ie9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade jqueryui version: Fix applied closing http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5370 . This will be in jQuery UI 1.8.6.